# How to upload a nexus artifact with the httpRequest Jenkins plugin

Tags: post, jenkins, groovy, httprequest, jenkins-pipeline

is there a way to upload a nexus artifact with the [httpRequest](https://github.com/jenkinsci/http-request-plugin) Jenkins plugin. I did try to upload it with:

```
String basicAuthString = "Basic " + "${user}:${password}".bytes.encodeBase64().toString()

String formBody = 'r=temp&g=org.codehaus.groovy&a=groovy-binary&v=2.3.7&p=zip&file=@groovy-binary.zip&hasPom=false'

def response = httpRequest contentType: 'APPLICATION_FORM', requestBody: formBody, consoleLogResponseBody: true, customHeaders: [[maskValue: false, name: 'Authorization', value: basicAuthString]], httpMode: 'POST', url: this.env.NEXUS_UPLOAD_URL
```

unfortunately, I'm getting the following error

```
Response Code: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Response: 
<html><body><error>Deployment tried with both 'packaging' and/or 'extension' being empty! One of these values is mandatory!</error></body></html>`
```

I'm doing something wrong? Is it possible to use this plugin at all?

Comment: You can use [Nexus  Artifact Uploader](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Nexus+Artifact+Uploader) plugin to upload the maven artifacts to Nexus.

Comment: Did u find a way using http?

Comment: Only way that works seems to be `sh` and `curl`

Answer (score 1):

Currently there are no ways to upload it with this plugin just because nexus is waiting form upload. When you upload file with other inputs you need to use

`Content-Type: multipart/form-data`.

In current version httpRequest Plugin doesn't have such `contentType`.

Answer (score 0):

yes this works, with a simple "PUT" , atleast when pushing to a "raw" repo

```
httpRequest authentication: 'auth_user', httpMode: 'PUT', requestBody: writeYaml(data: data, returnText: true), url "$(env.NEXUS_URL)/repository/upload_repo/test.yaml", wrapAsMultipart: false
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload file as raw i.e., without any multi-part specs. Here is a tested working example to publish 'mycustompackage-1.0-0.rpm' to Nexus Yum repo. You can follow the same pattern for Maven repo.

```
String authHeaderValue = 'Basic ' + 'myUserName:myPassword'.bytes.encodeBase64().toString()

def response = httpRequest  url: 'https://nexus.myorg.com/repository/my-yum-repo/rhel/8.5/os/x86_64/packages/mycustompackage-1.0-0.rpm',
                            customHeaders: [ [name: 'Authorization', value: authHeaderValue ] ],
                            httpMode: 'PUT',
                            uploadFile: '/tmp/mycustompackage-1.0-0.rpm',
                            wrapAsMultipart: false

assert response.status.equals(200) : "Upload FAILED !! Expected '200' HTTP response code (response code='${response.status}', response text=\n${response.content})"
```